# Counting how often a defined specific folder opened by users

Tags: java

I don't think if this is possible to count how many users have been opened a specific folder. I would greatly appreciated to anyone who can share a knowledge and idea regarding to this matter and also thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a folder in the filesystem, then this is only possible if the underlying operating system provides that functionality. Afaik no OS is providing this out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for your response Heiko Rupp. But I'm trying to code this in java, that is why I'm asking if this is possible to code. Thanks

Comment: Check `JNotify` http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/ to count any file event occurs in a particular directory. I am not sure whether it can track directory event itself or not.